# Retrieve Columns from Relational Database at Once

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

In order to simplify the problem, let's assume this is for a school database, and we have 3 tables. In this school the student can participate in multiple courses which have multiple lessons, and we store in the DB the information about the available courses, each course lessons and which courses and lessons the student is currently studying.

Table `courses` has 2 columns, `cs_id` and `cs_name`. Table `lessons` has 3 columns, `ls_course` which stores the ID of the course the lesson is from, `ls_number` —a sequential number that identifies the lesson within the course— and `ls_name`. The last table `students` stores the student ID, `st_id`, the course ID and current lesson in that course, `st_course` and `st_lesson`. Some sample data:

```
courses
+-------+----------+
| cs_id | cs_name  |
+-------+----------+
|     1 | Course A |
|     2 | Course B |
+-------+----------+

lessons
+-----------+-----------+--------------+
| ls_course | ls_number | ls_name      |
+-----------+-----------+--------------+
|         1 |         1 | Lesson One   |
|         1 |         2 | Lesson Two   |
|         1 |         3 | Lesson Three |
|         2 |         1 | Lesson One   |
|         2 |         2 | Lesson Two   |
|         2 |         3 | Lesson Three |
+-----------+-----------+--------------+

students
+-------+-----------+-----------+
| st_id | st_course | st_lesson |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
|     1 |         1 |         2 |
|     2 |         1 |         3 |
|     2 |         2 |         2 |
+-------+-----------+-----------+
```

As you can see we currently have 2 students, and the student with ID 2 is currently taking 2 courses at once. In Course A, she is in the third lesson and in Course B, in Lesson Two. What I want is to retrieve the listing for the courses one student is currently in. But not as:

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE st_id = 2;
```

This returns the filtered rows, but I'd like to retrieve the course and lesson ID *and* names for them. To get the course name column I'd do this:

```
SELECT s.*, c.cs_name
FROM students s, courses c
WHERE s.st_id = 2 AND s.st_course = c.cs_id
```

Which results in:

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| st_id | st_course | st_lesson | cs_name  |
+-------+-----------+-----------+----------+
|     2 |         1 |         3 | Course A |
|     2 |         2 |         2 | Course B |
+-------+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

The far I can get is:

```
SELECT s.*, c.cs_name, l.ls_name
FROM students s, courses c, lessons l
WHERE 
    s.st_id = 2            AND
    s.st_course = c.cs_id  AND
    s.st_lesson = l.ls_number
```

But how can I retrieve the lesson ID and chapter to check for a match in the lessons table, is it possible at all? The result I want is:

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+----------+--------------+
| st_id | st_course | st_lesson | cs_name  | ls_name      |
+-------+-----------+-----------+----------+--------------+
|     2 |         1 |         3 | Course A | Lesson Three |
|     2 |         2 |         2 | Course B | Lesson Two   |
+-------+-----------+-----------+----------+--------------+
```

Comment: Regarding the Lesson names, they aren't all the same for each course as in this example. This is just an oversimplification of what I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query is wrong:

```
 SELECT s.*, c.cs_name, l.ls_name
    FROM students s, courses c, lessons l
    WHERE 
        s.st_id = 2            AND
        s.st_course = c.cs_id  AND
        s.st_lesson = l.ls_number
```

You need also to match **st_course** to **ls_course**

```
 SELECT s.*, c.cs_name, l.ls_name
    FROM students s, courses c, lessons l
    WHERE 
        s.st_id = 2            AND
        s.st_course = c.cs_id  AND
        (s.st_lesson = l.ls_number AND st.st_course=l.ls_course)
```

I would also recommend using the current JOIN syntax, i.e.

```
SELECT s.*, c.cs_name, l.ls_name
FROM students s 
JOIN courses c ON c.cs_id=s.st_course
JOIN lessons l ON (s.st_lesson=l.ls_number AND st.st_course=l.ls_course)
WHERE s.st_id = 2
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it was incorrect, I just wrote that as the closest possible query to what I want. Yours is just perfect. And thanks for the `JOIN` alternative, which I hadn't imagined.

Comment: I think you'll find the JOIN syntax more readable.   Glad it is working